# Is ActiveMQ's failover mechanism supported by C# (openwire) & python (stomp) clients?

Tags: c#, python, activemq-classic, stomp, nms

I'd like to use ActiveMQ to connect python service with C# clients.
Is there a way to specify failover connection in C# (openwire) and python (Stomp)?

The ActiveMQ will be configured [Shared File System Master Slave.](http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# client supports failover see: http://issues.apache.org/activemq/browse/AMQNET-26.
Python client probably doesn't support it.

Comment: Are there any python clients with failover support now? I have searched a bit but could not find any.

Comment: @Buchi I haven't found a failover client so we used a simple home grown queues based on sql database